# How to uninstall Garena Plus from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wine

Ok guys so I downloaded and installed garena plus with wine but something wasn't working so now I want to uninstall it. I'm new on Linux and it's hard for me to figure out where the application is installed. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

- Click the windows key to open up unity. ("dash home" the top left icon on the desktop toolbar)
- Type in:  uninstall wine software.
- Choose/select your software in the list that follows.
- Press the modify/remove button.
- Follow onscreen instructions of your software. (if any)
- You should be done.